# Can I tap into the inline SOQL results with a string field value?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, inline

I am curious on how I would be able to pull out a dynamic field value from an in-line SOQL query. Is this possible? I have tried with no luck but wasn't sure if there was another way.

```
Decimal platinumNum = 12;
String platField = 'Platinum_' + platinumNum + '_Approval_Amount__c';
String soqlQuery = 'SELECT Id, Platinum_Term__c, ' + platField + ' FROM Decision__c ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1';   
List<Decision__c> listolivia =  database.query(soqlQuery);
system.debug('----> ' + listolivia[0].platField);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use sobject [`get`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) method, in order to get value of the sobject field dynamicaly:

```
system.debug('----> ' + listolivia[0].get(platField));
```